# Affect a server with remote PHP

Tags: php, server-side-includes

I'm currently trying to allow my remote server(B) to affect my local server(A) with a php include.
As a small test I put a php file in server A that include a file from server B, I allowed including urls via php.ini and changed my user agent.

The file on server B include code to create a small test file that is supposed to be created on server A. The problem is that everytime I run server A's include the file gets created on server B, when I really want it created on server A.

Server A's code:

```
include("http://www.XXXXXXXXX.com/Test.php");
```

Server B's code:

```
   $ourFileName = "testFile.txt";
   $ourFileHandle = fopen($ourFileName, 'w') or die("can't open file");
   fclose($ourFileHandle);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Server B, place the following line in your `.htaccess` file:

```
AddType text/plain .php
```

You need the *code* to be output by Server B to be read by Server A. At the moment it's being processed on Server A.

*This will make your code visible to the public.* It will also prevent any *other* PHP from being executed in that directory. You can use a `<Files>` directive to make it only apply to particular files, but it will always be available to the public. There are ways to restrict access there, both in PHP and in `.htaccess`.

If you don't want that to happen, there are ways to do that too but they're a bit more complex.

**EDIT** *to respond to request*
If you want to still execute PHP on Server B and selectively include files, I'd suggest creating a new file `includer.php` with content like the following:

```
<?php
if ('my-secret-key' == $_GET['auth']) {
    if (is_readable($_GET['file'])) {
        header('Content-type: text/plain');
        echo file_get_contents($_GET['file']);
    } else {
        header('Status: 404 Not found');
        header('Content-type: text/plain');
        die('<?php /* File not found */ ?>');
    }
} else {
    header('Status: 403 Forbidden');
    header('Content-type: text/plain');
    die('You do not have permission to access this page.');
}
```

And then on your Server A:

```
include ('http://example.com/includer.php?auth=my-secret-key&file=Test.php');
```

You should also look at using [`basename()`](http://php.net/basename) on `$_GET['file']` on Server B if you can, to improve security, and [`hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php)ing your `auth` parameter.

Comment: Thankyou, hmm what other ways are there?
Cause some code I want in plain text and other code I just want the output. Cause the included file on server B will be split into functions.

Comment: @user744319 I've just added a script which you can use.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple security issues raised by what you are doing.  While php is very flexible and can be configured to do such things, I would not recommend the way you are doing it.

There are others ways to have server 'a' create files on remote host 'b'.

Personnaly, I am very fond of the [ssh functions](http://php.net/manual/fr/book.ssh2.php) to do remote tasks in a relatively secure manner.

Comment: Thankyou for the warning and providing an alternative. As far as security issues go, the included file has authentication processes in place in order to stop any type of unauthorized access to server B's functions.